# why SYSTEM service can't read HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run?

Tags: c, regedit

I run a SYSTEM service but cannot read **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.**

but run with current user can do.

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD dwType=0;
TCHAR szValueName[MAXBYTE]={0};
TCHAR szValueKey[MAXBYTE]={0};
DWORD dwBufferSize=MAXBYTE;
DWORD dwKeySize=MAXBYTE;
if(RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",&hKey)!=ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return;
}

int i=0;
while(TRUE)
{
    if(RegEnumValue(hKey,i,szValueName,&dwBufferSize,NULL,&dwType,(LPBYTE)szValueKey,&dwKeySize)==ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        break;
    }
    printf("%s\n",szValueName);
    i++;
    dwBufferSize = MAXBYTE;
    dwKeySize = MAXBYTE;
    ZeroMemory(szValueName,MAXBYTE);
    ZeroMemory(szValueKey,MAXBYTE);
}
```

Comment: there is no current user for a system service

Comment: so how can I start service with current user?

Comment: or how to read it with system service?

Comment: You use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive.

Comment: This question should show you how to impersonate the logged in user from a service: [How to impersonate a user from a service correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796409/how-to-impersonate-a-user-from-a-service-correctly)